# Cannot redeclare function error in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two plugins in which I am initializing the sdk for data logging. The main concern is that whenever I put the **sdk **initialization code in second plugin, I get a following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare wpb_dynamic_init() (previously declared in C:\Users\WPB\Local Sites\wpb-sdk-site\app\public\wp-content\plugins\sdk-test-plugin\wpb-sdk\start.php:14) in C:\Users\WPB\Local Sites\wpb-sdk-site\app\public\wp-content\plugins\related-posts-thumbnails\wpb-sdk\start.php on line 18

The code I am using in the two plugins is:
**Plugin One: sdk-test-plugin**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'stp_wpb' ) ) {
    // Create a helper function for easy SDK access.
    function stp_wpb() {
        global $stp_wpb;

        if ( ! isset( $stp_wpb ) ) {
            // Include  SDK.
            require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/wpb-sdk/start.php';
            $stp_wpb = wpb_dynamic_init( array(
                    'id'    => 10,
                    'slug' => 'sdk-test-plugin',
                    'type' => 'plugin',
                    'public_key' => '7e240de74fb1ed08fa08d38063f6a691462a815',
                    'is_premium' => false,
                    'has_addons' => false,
                    'has_paid_plans' => false,
                    'menu' => array()
                ) );
        }

        return $stp_wpb;
    }

    // Init .
    stp_wpb();
    // Signal that SDK was initiated.
    do_action( 'stp_wpb_loaded' );
}
```

**Second Plugin: related-posts-thumbnails**

```
if (!function_exists('rpt_wpb')) {
    // Create a helper function for easy SDK access.
    function rpt_wpb()
    {
        global $rpt_wpb;

        if (!isset($rpt_wpb)) {
            // Include  SDK.
            require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/wpb-sdk/start.php';
            $rpt_wpb = wpb_dynamic_init(array(
                'id' => 7,
                'slug' => 'related-posts-thumbnails',
                'type' => 'plugin',
                'public_key' => '7e240de74fb1ed08fa08d38063f6a691462a815',
                'is_premium' => false,
                'has_addons' => false,
                'has_paid_plans' => false,
                'menu' => array()
            ));
        }

        return $rpt_wpb;
    }

    // Init .
    rpt_wpb();
    // Signal that SDK was initiated.
    do_action('rpt_wpb_loaded');
}
```

**the start.php file (sdk file)**

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/require.php';
function wpb_dynamic_init($module)
{
    $wpb = Logger::instance($module['id'], $module['slug'], true);
    // $wpb->dynamic_init($module);
    return $wpb;
}
```

**the require.php file**

```
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/config.php';
require_once WPB_SDK_DIR_INCLUDES . '/class-wpb-sdk-logger.php';
```

**And the logger class (class-wpb-sdk-logger.php)**

```
<?php

/**
 * Logger responsible for gathering user logs and send.
 * In effort to provide better customer experience.
 *
 * @since 2.0.1
 */

/**
 * Class responsible for logs data collection.
 */
class Logger
{
    private static $_instances = array();
    private $_module_id;
    private $_slug;
    /**
     * Class constructor.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function __construct($module_id, $slug = false, $is_init = false)
    {
        if ( ! $is_init && ! is_numeric($module_id) && ! is_string($slug)) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->_module_id = $module_id;
        $this->_slug = $slug;
        $this->hooks();
    }

    public static function instance($module_id, $slug = false, $is_init = false)
    {
        if (empty($module_id)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$is_init && true === $slug) {
            $is_init = true;
        }
        $key = 'm_' . $module_id;

        if (!isset(self::$_instances[$key])) {
            self::$_instances[$key] = new Logger($module_id, $slug, $is_init);
        }

        return self::$_instances[$key];
    }
}
```

Now let me know how to fix this issue as I have created the different instances but still I get issue of **Cannot redeclare wpb_dynamic_init()**

Comment: Wrap the `function_exists` around like the others do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how start.php is included, but probably it's included more than once.

Quick fix, surrounding your `wpb_dynamic_init` with

```php
if (!function_exists('wpb_dynamic_init')) {
    // your function
}
```

Better solution, find why start.php is included many times. You can use [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/debug_backtrace)  in start.php to visualize the calls-stack

Comment: the redeclaration issue is solved. But now I get the data of the last plugin that have the sdk. Like if I have plugin one and plugin two it will show data on only plugin two in activation as well as deactivation

Comment: check passed argument $module when you call wpb_dynamic_init($module).
Maybe both plugins use the same value for $module